# Destructor for class that holds pointer to object

Tags: c++, oop

Lets say we have a class that holds a pointer member to another object. If I delete that pointer in the destructor I get an error (and I understand why).

My question is : is it possible to overcome that without memory leaks ?

Here is a demo of what I am doing.

```
class A {
    public:
    ~A() { cout<< "~A()" <<endl; }
};

class B {
    A *pA;
    public:
    B(A* pA) {
        this->pA = pA;
    }
    ~B() { 
                delete pA;
        cout<<"~B()"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    {
        B b2(new A()); //deletes A, deletes B, no memory leaks
    }
    {
        B b(&a); //deletes A, error.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all that's not memory leak, but an **undefined behavior**, a more serious issue. An attempt is made to deallocate a memory from wrong region.
One should use `delete/delete[]/free()` only on corresponding `new/new[]/malloc()`.

There is no full proof and architecture independent way, just adhere to good programming practices.

May not be perfect always, but one way is to overload `new` and `delete` and hold a `std::map` like data structure. Whenever `new` is called add the pointer to it. Upon `delete` you can make check if the pointer exists or not, if the allocation was of type `new` or `new[]` etc..
Definitely this will affect your performance, so you need to keep it under debug mode.

Answer (score 2):

You have two objects that think they own a dynamically allocated object and try to delete it. The solution is to decide who should own the object, and to implement the correct copy/assignment behaviour with the help of the appropriate smart pointer:

1. Do `A` and `B` deal with dynamically allocated objects at all? There is no way of knowing this from a raw pointer, so the design has to be revised to cover one case or the other. Assuming dynamic object allocation, then
2. Each object owns its own copy: Implement the rule of three in `A` or `B`, and have only one of the two delete. You can use a scoped pointer to simplify memory management (`boost_scoped_ptr`, or `std::unique_ptr`).
3. Unique ownership: a single object owns the copy: Use `std::unique_ptr`. Disallow copy and assignment, allow move-copy and move-assignment
4. Shared ownership: Nobody/everybody owns the object. It gets deleted when nobody references it: use `std::shared_ptr`

Comment: Will smart pointer know that the address is from `new` or from stack?  I don't think so. There is no foolproof way for this kind of problems. Also the OP doesn't talk about multiple objects sharing the memory. It's just 1 at a time, look at the `{}` scoping.

Comment: +1 but your last point sort of contradicts itself. "Shared ownership" followed straight after by "nobody owns the object".

Comment: @dreamlax if everyone owns something, then nobody owns it :-) But I will try to rephrase it to make it clearer.

Comment: @iammilind You're right. I added a first point dealing with this.

Answer (score 1):

You must tell `B`, when it owns the pointer and when it doesn't.

Add an additional flag telling when

```
class B {
    bool owner;
    A *pA;
    public:
    B(A* pA, bool bOwner) : owner(bOwner) {
        this->pA = pA;
    }
    ~B() { 
        if (owner)
            delete pA;
        cout<<"~B()"<<endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    {
        B b2(new A(), true); //deletes A, destroys B, no memory leaks
    }
    {
        B b(&a, false); //destroys B, ok.
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How will this code handle following situation: `B b(foo(), ??);` where `foo()` returns a pointer.

Comment: @iammilind It depends on whether `b` will own the pointer, of course. If it does, use `B b(foo(), true)`, if it doesn't `B b(foo(), false)`.

Comment: To be over simplistic ... `A* foo () { static A a; return (bool)? new A : &a; }`

Comment: @iammilind If you want to make something up, then do something complete. This doesn't even compile. Assume your bool is an argument to `foo()`, then you give the same argument to `B`, straightforward and simple.

Comment: @iammilind Just to be clear, you shouldn't have such code in the first place.